# Hyphen/Dash to be included in regex word boundary \b

Tags: regex, grep, word-boundary, character-class

Simply put:

```
echo "xxxxx Tyyy zzzzz" | egrep "\byyy\b"
```

(no match which is correct)

```
echo "xxxxx T-yyy zzzzz" | egrep "\byyy\b" 
xxxxx T-yyy zzzzz
```

I dont want it to match like it does in the second expression, please advise how I can achieve this, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
echo "xxxxx T-yyy zzzzz" | grep -E "(^|[^-])\byyy\b([^-]|$)"
```

Where `(^|[^-])\byyy\b([^-]|$)` will match start or non-hyphen on LHS and end or non-hyphen on RHS of the matched word `yyy`.